# Import ZAP Docker Image in GitLab

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use ZAP in my GitLab repository.
(link to the docker image for ZAP: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker)

But during the execution of the script in the 'yml' file, I got the 'proxy' error, now instead, after some modifications, I get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 621, in main
     raise RuntimeError ('Click will abort further execution'

RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python is configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment. Either switch to Python 2 or consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/ for mitigation steps.
```

Has anyone already had the same problem or knows how I could solve it? 
Thank you all

Comment: The idea behind this work is to try to use ZAP CLI directly from GitLab (in order to automate the security tests on a project). To do this, I imported this docker image into my YML file and I'm trying to execute the scan commands directly from here. The command I'm using to do this is "docker run -i owasp / zap2docker-weekly zap-cli active-scan https://targetwebsite" as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add those to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ARG LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ARG LANG=C.UTF-8
```

see [this](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/python3/)

**Update**

try the following:

```
docker run -i -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 -e LANG=C.UTF-8 owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-cli active-scan targetwebsite
```

Comment: I saw that, but i'm getting the image from here: [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-weekly) so where or how i can add those lines?

Comment: you can set those ENV also in your gitlab yml file

Comment: I copy/pasted that in my yml but it doesn't recognize it :(

Comment: please provide what are you doing in the question

Comment: with this also `-e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 -e LANG=C.UTF-8 ` ? it worked for me

Comment: `docker run -i -e LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 -e LANG=C.UTF-8` works good for the Encoding error (thank you very much), so problem solved. Now i got another error related to the proxy -.-