# GitLab CI implementation of ZAP

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, zap

i'm working on a GitLab CI implementation of ZAP.

What i'm trying to archive, is to perform tests directly in the project, and check the results in the pipeline. I need your help to understand how i can write a yml file to test all the urls present in the application to test.
Is there anyone who already did this?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

GitLab Team member here. I definitely don't pretend to be an expert on ZAP and how to integrate it, however, [this StackOverflow thread seems like a promising example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762658/import-zap-docker-image-in-gitlab?rq=1) of executing successfully using something like Docker.

Let me know if this reply misses the mark, but I *hope* it at least gets you one step closer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. This is actually what i've already archived. You run the command "zap http://target.com" and you analyze the website. What i'm trying now, is in a project, to perform the scan of the entire project. Example: '- docker exec $OWASP_CONTAINER zap-cli -v -p $ZAP_API_PORT active-scan http://$PENTEST_IP/ ' this, in order to implement automation (you don't have to scan all the possible URLs inside a page, you just use a "variable")